# Alternation group without repetitions using a single regex in a Canvas Quiz

Tags: regex, canvas-lms

I work with Canvas in a middle school and am constructing quizzes which contain a question type called "fill-in-the-blank". A grading option for this type of question is to compare what the student typed in to a regex. The Quiz settings only allow me to enter a single regex and if the input matches the question is counted as correct. This is simple to do for single or few word answers. But I would like to ask something like, "list three different examples of environmental stimuli, ended with a period". So a correct input string might be the following:

rain. bright sunlight. a dog's bark.

but an incorrect input string would be:

water. water. a bicycle.

I can match individual phrases and split them using `([\w\s']*[^\.]?)`. This yields three matches in a regex tester. But I need to go further.

I need to check each phrase for a keyword, and then check if that keyword has been used before. Essentially, I need to match an alternation group without repetitions using a single regex pattern. Can this be done?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have an alternation group without repetitions. This is a bit complex and has some limitations but can be done.

We need to

- allow random filler words, punctuation, etc before and after the answers; basically, anything that is not an answer `(?:(?!(?:\1|\2|\3)).)*`
- and define the answers (with `\b` word boundaries as needed) in an alternation group in a way that does not allow repetitions

i.e. a pattern like this using the regex flags gxi (or inlining (some of) them `(?x)(?i)`

```
^                                    # begin of string
(?:(?!(?:\1|\2|\3)).)*?              # ungreedy anything that is not captured by group 1,2,or 3
   (                                 # 1th capturing group
    (?:\brain\b|\bsunlight\b|\bbark) # Alternation group (answers) \b word-boundaries as needed
   )
(?:(?!(?:\1|\2|\3)).)*?              # ungreedy anything that is not captured by group 1,2,or 3
   (                                 # 3th capturing group
    (?:(?!(?:\1|\3))(?:\brain\b|\bsunlight\b|\bbark)) # Answers not captured in group 1 or 3
   )
(?:(?!(?:\1|\2|\3)).)*?              # ungreedy anything that is not captured by group 1,2,or 3
   (                                 # 4th capturing group
    (?:(?!(?:\2|\3))(?:\brain\b|\bsunlight\b|\bbark)) # Answers not captured by group 2 or 3
   )
(?:(?!(?:\1|\2|\3)).)*               # anything that is not captured by group 1,2,or 3
$                                    # end of string
```

The pattern could be simplified but I tried to keep the pattern readable (Though,  techniques like `(?(DEFINE).(?"answers"))` could help us to make the regex more maintainable.)

[Ruby Rublar Demo](https://rubular.com/r/z9UDSfNS5vfS8n) (`g`|global, and `m`|multiline flags are default on tubular),
[PCRE Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NMBvOT/1) (using `gmxi`-flags)
Quizzes are using Ruby regular expressions which are very similar to PCRE but not exactly the same.

This shows the basic idea and should get you started. Nonetheless, a regex is not a linguistics tool nor an AI. The pattern is context-free and does not verify if the answers make actual sense, e.g. if we define `rain|sunlight|bark` as possible answers this is valid:

> Barking elephant, green Sunlight, purple rain, and other non-sense

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I realize regex is not a language tool but right now it is the only option I have within Canvas other than (1)entering every literal permutation I can think of or (2)hand grading 160 papers. I will try your suggestion!

Comment: I tried your suggestion in the online regex tester I am using on the phrase "rain. bright sunlight. a dog's bark." and it failed to find a match. I am trying to figure out why it doesn't find a match, but my debugging has failed so far. I would be happy to use the DEFINE structure, but I'm not sure how it fits in with the rest of what you gave me. Some additional help would be great!

Comment: @Nyssa73 The `(?(DEFINE)(?'subroutine'regex))` group is only in Perl and PCRE available but not in Ruby; the online demo's I provided are working, which one's do you refer to?

Comment: Too bad about the DEFINE. I am using regex101.com. I copied the pattern you posted (^...$), removed all of the comments, and put it in the regular expression window in the tester. I then put the string "rain. bright sunlight. a dog's bark." in the Test String window. The result is "no match". Am I being stupid?

Comment: Argh! I just saw your link to the Ruby Demo! I'll play around with that tester. It must have failed because regex101.com is a PCRE tester?

Comment: @Nyssa73 no, but you need to use some extra regex flags specifically `x` and `i`; I should have pointed this out. Click on the PCRE Demo link above to see it in action; if your Quiz portlet does not allow to specify extra flags we can define them inline, prefixing the regex pattern with `(?x)(?i)`

Comment: regex101 has different regex flavors, select them on the left; unfortunately, Ruby-regex is not among them; in fact, the Ruby flavor is very close to Perl but there are still some differences.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks again!!